# Memory reallocation causes segmentation fault on loop

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc, realloc, calloc

What I'm doing here is basically joining to a global array (optimisedMesh) some smaller arrays (Bx, By, and Bz). As you can see the content and size of Bx, By and Bz is set on the b and c loops. Once they are fully defined they are joined to optimisedMesh.
This process should happen every "a" for loop.

I've found two problems trying this. The first one is that when I call free(Bx); once I've finished needing this array, the debugger returns me a segmentation fault, I'm not sure why.

The second one happens on the second loop of the "a" for loop. On the first loop 
the realloc seems to work fine, but on the second it returns the 0x0 address, which causes a segmentation fault further in the code.

Also, I've ommited the By and Bz code because it looks exactly the same as Bx.

Thanks for your time.

```
    int* LBxIA = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*));    int* LBxIB = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*)); int* LByIA = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*)); int* LByIB = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*)); int* LBzIA = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*)); int* LBzIB = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*));
    int* LBxFA = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*));    int* LBxFB = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*)); int* LByFA = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*)); int* LByFB = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*)); int* LBzFA = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*)); int* LBzFB = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*));

    Quad** Bx = (Quad**) calloc(1,sizeof(Quad*));

    int maxSize = Math::maxof(xLenght,yLenght,zLenght);
    for(int a = 0; a < maxSize; a++){
        int BxCount = 0; int ByCount = 0; int BzCount = 0;
        Bx = (Quad**) realloc(Bx,sizeof(Quad*));

        for(int b = 0; b < maxSize; b++){   
            for(int c = 0; c < maxSize; c++){
                //Bx
                if(a <xLenght && b < yLenght && c < zLenght){
                    if(cubes[a][b][c] != nullptr){
                        if(!cubes[a][b][c]->faces[FACE_LEFT].hidden){
                            if(!LBxIA){
                                LBxIA = new int(c);
                            }else{
                                LBxFA = new int(c);
                            }
                        }else{
                            if(LBxIA && LBxFA){
                                BxCount++;
                                Bx = (Quad**) realloc(Bx, BxCount * sizeof(Quad*));
                                Bx[BxCount - 1] = new Quad(Vector3(a,b,*LBxIA),Vector3(a,b,*LBxFA),Vector3(a,b+1,*LBxIA),Vector3(a,b+1,*LBxFA));
                                LBxIA = nullptr;
                                LBxFA = nullptr;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(LBxIA && LBxFA){
                            BxCount++;
                            Bx = (Quad**) realloc(Bx, BxCount * sizeof(Quad*));
                            Bx[BxCount-1] = new Quad(Vector3(a,b,*LBxIA),Vector3(a,b,*LBxFA),Vector3(a,b+1,*LBxIA),Vector3(a,b+1,*LBxFA));
                            LBxIA = nullptr;
                            LBxFA = nullptr;

                        }
                        if(LBxIB && LBxFB){
                            BxCount++;
                            Bx = (Quad**) realloc(Bx, BxCount * sizeof(Quad*));
                            Bx[BxCount-1] = new Quad(Vector3(a+1,b,*LBxIB),Vector3(a+1,b,*LBxFB),Vector3(a+1,b+1,*LBxIB),Vector3(a+1,b+1,*LBxFB));
                            LBxIB = nullptr;
                            LBxFB = nullptr;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        optimisedMeshCount += (BxCount + ByCount + BzCount)*sizeof(Quad*);
        optimisedMesh = (Quad**) realloc(optimisedMesh, optimisedMeshCount);
        copy(Bx, Bx + BxCount*sizeof(Quad*), optimisedMesh + (optimisedMeshCount - (BxCount + ByCount + BzCount)*sizeof(Quad*)));
        copy(By, By + ByCount*sizeof(Quad*), optimisedMesh + (optimisedMeshCount - (BxCount + ByCount + BzCount)*sizeof(Quad*)) + BxCount*sizeof(Quad*));//TODO Aquí error
        copy(Bz, Bz + BzCount*sizeof(Quad*), optimisedMesh + (optimisedMeshCount - (BxCount + ByCount + BzCount)*sizeof(Quad*)) + BxCount*sizeof(Quad*) + ByCount*sizeof(Quad*));
        free(Bx);
    }
```

Comment: How does mixing memory allocators work, for example: `int* LBxIA = (int*) calloc (1,sizeof(int*));` and later `LBxIA = new int(c);`  ?  I also see calls to `new` with no calls to `delete`.  As @MichaelBurr suggests you can replace most of this with `std::vector`

Comment: In such cases, using a memory checker like valgrind can be extremely helpful. For your actual problem, the pointer arithmetic in the copy statements seems wrong; adding a number to optimisedMesh won't increment the pointer in bytes but rather in "Quad"s. Anyway, why don't you use `std::vector` for memory management?

Comment: Have your tried running under valgrind?  Have you considered using `vector<>` which handles all this dynamic allocation for growing arrays for you?

Comment: Also, in `copy(Bx, Bx + BxCount*sizeof(Quad*)` the addition of a pointer and a number is already scaled by the size if the object pointed to -- `p+1` doesn't point one byte after `p`, but one object after `p`. Do you *really* want to scale it one more time here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, the problem is with the three [`copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) lines.

`copy` expects begin and end of some container or memory range. In your case you provide `Bx`, which is fine, and `Bx + BxCount*sizeof(Quad*)`, which is way beyond the end of `Bx` memory.

This is because `Bx + 1` is not `Bx` + 1 byte, but `&Bx[1]`, which is the second element. Equally, `Bx + BxCount` would be the "end" as expected by `copy`.

This means `Bx + BxCount*sizeof(Quad*)` is, on a 64 bit system, eight times as much beyond the end of `Bx` memory range. Same goes for `optimisedMesh`, `By` and `Bz`. As a consequence, you copy too many elements and as a result get memory corruption.

---

Using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and storing `Quad`s instead of pointers to `Quad`

```
std::vector<Quad> Bx, By, Bz, optimisedMesh;
for (int a = 0; a < maxSize; a++) {
    Bx.clear();
    for (int b = 0; b < maxSize; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < maxSize; c++) {
            // ...
            Quad qx(Vector3(a,b,*LBxIA),
                   Vector3(a,b,*LBxFA),
                   Vector3(a,b+1,*LBxIA),
                   Vector3(a,b+1,*LBxFA));
            Bx.push_back(qx);
            // ...
        }
    }

    std::copy(Bx.begin(), Bx.end(), std::back_inserter(optimizedMesh));
    std::copy(By.begin(), By.end(), std::back_inserter(optimizedMesh));
    std::copy(Bz.begin(), Bz.end(), std::back_inserter(optimizedMesh));
}
```

As you can see, no explicit allocation, reallocation or freeing of memory, no counting of elements.

---

Unrelated, but you must also pay attention to `LBxIA = new int(c);` and `LBxIA = nullptr;`, which leaks memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem. Probably I got confused because the realloc actually needs the size in bytes. The other responses were also very useful, but I think this one was the clearest one.

Comment: This answer explains the reason for the segmentation fault, but the other suggestions (e.g. `std::vector`) help to make it more robust and also simplify the code.